# Mounting a countertop dishwasher above the sink?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

People put drying racks above the kitchen sink. I am thinking on mounting an appropriate console on the wall at the same height and put a compact dishwasher on it (it's only 25kg, the wall is a load bearing stone wall, yes, stone, this is Malta). What are the reasons *not* to do this? When trying to find photos of such arrangements I fail so I suspect something is wrong with my space saving idea. A completely new kitchen will be built so whatever plumbing is necessary can be made.

[image: drying rack above sink]

[image: dishwasher dimensions]

Comment: There's no particular benefit to putting it above the sink, for one thing. The drying racks are there so things can drip into the sink. The dishwasher shouldn't drip. It's also going to be an awkward/inconvenient height to load.

Comment: Mounting would important.  Unlike shelves/cabinets/racks, a dishwasher will have vibrations that could loosen mounts.  When the door is open, it will probably be right where a person walking by hits their head on it.

Comment: Do like that rack in the picture.  Much better than having a drying rack beside the sink, and then when the dishes are dry, moving them into cabinets.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, even if the dishwasher itself only weighs 25kg, the water (each liter is another kg) can add quite a bit, and the dishes add even more.

Second, it will be hard to move dishes safely in and out of the dishwasher because of the height.

And last, but not least, unless you mount this really high up, you will limit use of the sink. That may not seem like a big deal - after all, most of the dishes are going into the dishwasher! But the things that are *not* going into the dishwasher are typically the biggest items - pots and pans - which need the most room to work with when cleaning.

Far better is to either mount it beneath the counter or place it directly on the counter. 18" above the counter is not unreasonable for some storage shelves directly above a counter dishwasher.

Comment: Dishwashers (floor-standing ones in Europe anyway) only use about 10-12 litres per cycle.  That#'s split between wash and rinse, and normally 2 rinses at that.  A decent load of dishes would weigh more than the 4-6kg of water in the machine.  But I agree with the conclusion and  your other points are very valid.  If you mount it where you won't headbutt it, you won't be able to reach into it without steps and/or a long reach.